# Non-existence of $1$-dimensional tangent distributions on the sphere $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, vector-fields

I am reading about geometric quantization and real polarizations, and it is claimed that there exist no real polarizations on the sphere $S^2 \subset \Bbb R^3$ because every tangent field on $S^2$ must vanish in some point ("real polarization" = Lagrangian distribution with respect to some given symplectic form - but Lagrangeanity does not seem to matter in the argument, so just ignore it).

I don't understand the given reason. I agree that, if $X$ is a tangent field on $S^2$, then $\Bbb R X$ cannot be a distribution of constant dimension on $S^2$ because it must have dimension $0$ at those points where $X$ vanishes. What I don't understand, though, is why every $1$-dimensional distribution must be of the form $\Bbb R X$ for some $X$, in order for the argument in the first paragraph to be applicable. Could you please explain this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that locally any one-dimensional distribution is of the form $\mathbb R\cdot X$ for a non-vanishing local vector field $X$ on $S^2$. To get the global result, you need the fact that any real line bundle over $S^2$ has to be trivial since $S^2$ is simply connected. Thus you get a global non-vanishing section.

Comment: I *almost* understand you. It seems, though, that you make the silent assumption that a $1$-dimensional distribution is a line bundle. Is it so? Would its trivializations be induced by the trivializations of $TS^2$?

Comment: More or less by definition, a 1-dimensional distribution on a manifold is a line bunlde which is realized as a subbundle of the tangent bundle. In the definition it is usually not assumed that its local trivializations are related to trivializations of the tangent bundle (you only require that it is spanned by vector fields, which gives local trivializations). But it is not difficult to prove that you can always find common trivializations. However,  it is not neccesary (and not true in general) that the distribution is trivial over each subset on which the tangent bundle is trivial.

Comment: That's interesting! Is the same true for general distributions, or just for line bundles? Clearly every distribution is locally a vector bundle itself (the tangent bundle of some integral submanifold), but can this conclusion be globalized? What about *complex* line bundles?

Comment: It is true in general. Globalizing is not really an issue, since the definition of a vector bundle is only via local trivializations.